# PPA that depend on another PPA

Tags: ppa

I have a PPA with latest Qt Creator and I use another PPA with latest Qt5 that needed for QtC compile and run.

Is it possible for end-user simple add my PPA and automatically add dependment PPA? Or must I notify user that another PPA is used and he must add it manually? What is heppens when dependment PPA will be changed?

Comment: You must notify the user. See the description of [the GNOME3 Testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/testing).

Comment: @ByteCommander, thanks. Yes seems given question describes my problem too. So, only user notification.